# How can I tell this regex expression to ignore www urls and catch both ('Inter.ttf') and (Inter.ttf)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, python-re

so I currently have a regex expression which replaces css urls by appending `'/static/user'` to each url. However, I want to make this expression ignore www urls (https://www.google.com) and catch both instances of url('Inter-Black.ttf') and url(Inter-Black.ttf), with and without quotation marks.

This is my current code:

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<=url\(')/?(?=(?:.*?\.\w{3})'\))")
filez = re.sub(p, '/static/user/', filez)
```

I have also tried which does not work.

```
p = re.compile(r"^(?!.*(www))(?<=url\(')/?(?=(?:.*?\.\w{3})'\))")
filez = re.sub(p, '/static/user/', filez)
```

And currently use this solution in order to catch both quotes and non quotes. But ideally I would want a cleaner solution along with regex ignoring www urls.

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<=url\(')/?(?=(?:.*?\.\w{3})'\))")
filez = re.sub(p, '/static/user/', filez)
p = re.compile(r"(?<=url\()/?(?=(?:.*?\.\w{3})\))")
filez = re.sub(p, '/static/user/', filez)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an optional capture group with an if clause to account for the opening `'` matching with a closing `'`

```
(url\()(?!https?://www\.google\.com)(')?/?([^()']*)((?(2)')\))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(url\()` Capture **group 1**, match `url(`
- `(?!https?://www\.google\.com)` Negative lookahead, assert not the specific url
- `(')?` Optionally capture `'` in **group 2**
- `/?` Optionally match a leading `/`
- `([^()']*)` Capture **group 3**, match any char except `(` `)` or `'`
- `(` Capture **group 4**

  - `(?(2)')` If clause to check if group 2 exists, if it does, match `'`
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0Pxo8/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7BvzPo)

```
import re

filez = """url(https://www.google.com)
url('Inter-Black.ttf')
url(Inter-Black.ttf)
url('Inter-Black.ttf)
url('/fonts/user/Inter-Black.ttf')
url('/fonts/user/mywebsite/Inter-Black.ttf')
"""

p = r"(url\()(?!https?://www\.google\.com)(')?/?([^()']*)((?(2)')\))"
filez = re.sub(p, r"\1\2/static/user/\3\4", filez)
print(filez)
```

Output

```
url(https://www.google.com)
url('/static/user/Inter-Black.ttf')
url(/static/user/Inter-Black.ttf)
url('Inter-Black.ttf)
url('/static/user/fonts/user/Inter-Black.ttf')
url('/static/user/fonts/user/mywebsite/Inter-Black.ttf')
```

Comment: @JongbinWon In that case, you could shorted it to `(url\()(?!http://)(')?/?([^()']*)((?(2)')\))` See https://regex101.com/r/K9IGGN/1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does this also work if the url is url('/fonts/user/Inter-Black.ttf') or url('/fonts/user/mywebsite/Inter-Black.ttf')? How would I change the regex so it gets rid of the first / because if not then the output will be url('/static/user//fonts/user/Inter-Black.ttf') @The fourth bird

Answer (score 0):

Hope to help

```
import re

filez = """url(https://www.google.com)
url('Inter-Black.ttf')
url(Inter-Black.ttf)
"""


p = re.compile(r"(url\(\'?)((?!.*www).*\.\w{3})(\'?\))")

filez = re.sub(p, r'\1/static/user/\2\3', filez)

print(filez)
```

output:

```
url(https://www.google.com)
url('/static/user/Inter-Black.ttf')
url(/static/user/Inter-Black.ttf)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does this also work if the url is `url('/fonts/user/Inter-Black.ttf')` or `url('/fonts/user/mywebsite/Inter-Black.ttf')`? How would I change the regex so it gets rid of the first / because if not then the output will be `url('/staitic/user//fonts/user/Inter-Black.ttf')` @EEEEH